# Use Cassandra with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, cassandra

I want to make a login form with authentication function using username and password.
This is my config with MySQL :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
...
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
...
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
...
}
```

Now I want to change to using Cassandra instead. How can I create Cassandra datasource?

Beside I don't know how can the spring-security validate the username and password which submit from login form. What should I do with POST requested function ? (ex :`login()` in `UserController`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("password");
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}
```

Then you should change your driverClassName to `org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver`

And your url as well; `jdbc:cassandra://localhost:8988/keyspace`